ZED CAMERA API python3 problem with tracking object
guys.
In my tracking system, two classes are used to designate cones and people. However, problems arise: when objects overlap, the class can sometimes be erroneously changed. For example, when I approach a cone, the system may incorrectly update the key points and assign me the class of a cone due to a greater number of my key points. I need help configuring the system so that it does not change the object class when it is overlapped by another object.
Could you advise how to set up the tracking to prevent this problem? Also, does ZED API use algorithms like SORT (Simple Online and Realtime Tracking) or Deep SORT, and how can I interact with these algorithms to adjust the identification of objects when they overlap?
SO i need methods of ZED's api to disable tracker or maybe load custom detection threshold update frame. So it my point of view, but i may wrong.

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

how to ask a good question:
how to ask
